# PyCharm remote interpreter via ssh Tunnel

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, pycharm, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I want to setup a remote python interpreter in Pycharm.

The remote interpreter is a non-public EC2 instance behind a public proxy.

Can I setup a SSH Tunnel via PyCharm or Terminal to allow me to pass in the EC2 IP in this dialog box?

[image]